# How do I stop the public from accessing my API stored in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a REST API running in Elastic Beanstalk. The urls used are accessible from any IP address worldwide. All I want to do is restrict access to the API's calls so that only my fixed IP address is able to use it. I've been unable to work out how to do this as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well do this by using the security group of instances being used under the hood.

Just go to the instance's Security Group and edit the inbound rule of security group and set it to your IP. This way only your IP can talk to the intances serving your ElasticBeanstalk env.

More details can be found below :

[Your AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Amazon EC2 Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html)

Comment: Alright, so I've configured that and now only my IP address is capable of any inbound or outbound traffic. But, now I get the following upon calling any function of the API in my browser (as well as a 500 internal server error when using it in an integrated Xamarin app):

```

<Error>

<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>

</Error>
```

Comment: It seems like your app needs to talk to the outside world which we have just restricted. Do you see any dependency like this?